# We choose $3$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. What is the probability that the three numbers that we chose are sides of a triangle $ABC$?

Tags: probability

We choose $3$ numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. What is the probability that the three numbers that we chose are sides of a triangle $ABC$?

The number of all possible outcomes are $$n={5\choose3}=\dfrac{5.4.3}{6}=10$$ I don't know if there's a smart way to count the good outcomes. $2;3;4$ and $3;4;5$ can be sides of a triangle. Am I missing something?

Comment: The only restriction is that no two side can be longer than the other two sides combined. You can count how many combinations fail this requirement: $(1,2,4),(1,2,5),(1,3,5)$.

Comment: $1$ cannot be one of the sides as sides are integers. So that leaves $4$ ways to choose sides and one of them does not work $2,3,5$

Comment: "The only restriction is that no two side can be longer than the other two sides combined."  They can't be equal either.  Unless the instructor is allowing for "trivial" triangles allowing angles of $0$ and $180$. .... which maybe he/she is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest distance between two points is a straight line.  Therefore the third side of a triangle must be shorter than the sum of the other two sides. So

> Triangle inequality:  If $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle then $a + b > c$.

So $1,3,5$ can not be the sides of a triangle because $1+3 < 5$.

So look and the ten triplets and see which can be triangles.

Bad:  $(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(1,2,5), (1,3,4), (1,3,5),(1,4,5)$ because $1 + \min(b,c) \le \max(b,c)$.

Good:  $(2,3,4)$ because $2 +3 > 4$.  Bad: $(2,3,5)$ because $2+3 \le 5$.

Good: $(2,4,5), (3,4,5)$ because $a + 4 > 5$ whenever $a > 1$.

So $3$ out of $10$ triplets are good and make triangles and $7$ out of $10$ are bad and don't make triangles because the longest side is not shorter than the sum of the two shorter sides.

......

Note:  A "degenerate triangle" is one where the three points are colinear and so that side $AB$ and $BC$ are actually superimposed on the side $AC$ and share the same points (and so $m\angle BAC = 0; m\angle ABC = 180; m\angle BCA = 0$).  This technically fits the definition of a "triangle".  And the "triangle inequality" usually used to describe properties of metrics and norms, is usually stated as:  if $A,B,C$ are three points then $d(A,B) + d(B,C) \ge d(B,C)$ allowing for equality which occurs only if the points are colinear.

You class *might* be considering those to be legitimate triangles.  I doubt it and I wouldn't count them as such... But if they are.....

Answer (score 0):

$(a,b,c)$ can be sides of a triangle iff $a \leq b+c$, $b \leq c+a$ and $c \leq a+b$. In your example, the couples that won’t work are $(1,2,4)$, $(1,2,5)$ and $(1,3,5)$. Therefore, the probability that the numbers we chose are sides of a triangle is $\frac{7}{10}$.

**EDIT:** If you consider that a degenerate triangle is not a triangle, then you may also exclude $(1,2,3)$, $(1,3,4)$, $(1,4,5)$ and $(2,3,5)$. In that case, the probability would be $\frac{3}{10}$.

Comment: $1,2,3$ and  $1,3,4$ and$1,4,5$ and $2,3,5$ won't work either.

Comment: You can't have equality.   The two sides will lie flat upon the third side.

Comment: Well, a degenerate triangle is technically a triangle. I don’t know how the op wants to deal with this case.

Comment: That is true...  We must determine if degenerate triangles (those with angles of $0, 0, 180$ so that they are two sides superimposed on a line segment) are allowed.  But I'd assume they are not.